# Plain RMI console client

Tags: java, user-interface, console, rmi

I'm working on a client-server application implemented with RMI where the client is a simple console application with several methods that the server can remotely invoke. When the client is started, it registers itself with the server and then it should just "hang" there and wait for invocations from the server (each method also prints some information using `System.out.println` and sometimes needs input from the user). How do I make the client just "hang" and wait?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any JVM that has exported remote objects will 'hang and wait' as long as those objects remain exported.